# Entity Framework Core Unable to Determine Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have two objects: User and Relationship. A User object is created for each user of my system and multiple relationships will be created for each user depending on how many people they add as friends. The objects look as follows

```
public class User : IdentityUser {}

public class Relationship {
   // User who created the relationship
   public User User {get;set;}

   // User who the creation user is friends with
   public User Friend {get;set;}

   // Enum of Status (Approved, Pending, Denied, Blocked)
   public RelationshipStatus RelationshipStatus {get;set;}

   public DateTime RelationshipCreationDate {get;set;}
}
```

Each user could have multiple records where they match `Relationship.User` and they could have multiple records where they match `Relationship.Friend`. I have my DbContext setup as follows in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Relationship>(relationship =>
    {
        relationship.HasOne(r => r.User).WithMany(u => u.Friends);                
    });            
}
```

I'm new to Entity so this is probably trivial - What am I missing to have the relationship setup as I have described? Thanks!

Edit: To Be more specific, here is the error that I'm getting:

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Relationship.Friend' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'`

Edit 2: After rethinking my process, I took a different approach and used the relationships to include followers and following, rather than a collective friends list (fits my business model better anyway). I achieved this with the following:

```
public class User : IdentityUser {
  [InverseProperty("Friend")]
  public List<Relationship> Followers {get;set;}

  [InverseProperty("User")]
  public List<Relationship> Following {get;set;}
}
```

I am curious if anyone has a solution to the original problem outside of my solution, however, this works for now and seems to fit me best.

Comment: Here is a good reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships.  Note that in the "Blog", example the one-to-many relationship between "Blog" and "Posts" is represented like this: `public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }`

Comment: @paulsm4 That post solved it. I approached it differently than I was originally. I'll update the question right now to include the new approach.

Comment: Cool - glad to hear it!  Thank you for posting back your solution - it will help others :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding to the User class a List of Relationships, i.e

```
   public class User : IdentityUser {
       List<Relationship> Relationships {get;set;}
   }
```

This might help EF fully understand the relationship.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I just tried that out and it looks like it's still not fully understanding the relationship. It understands that the user has friends (`Relationship.User == User`) but it doesn't seem to understand that a User can be tied to the `Friend` column as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to configure `many-to-many` with the same entity. To do so, write your `User` and `Relationship` model classes as follows:

```
public class User : IdentityUser 
{
   public List<Relationship> UserFriends { get; set; }
   public List<Relationship> FriendUsers { get; set; }
}

public class Relationship {

   public string UserId {get; set;} // `UserId` type is string as you are using default identity
   public User User {get;set;}

   public string FriendId {get; set;}
   public User Friend {get;set;}

   // Enum of Status (Approved, Pending, Denied, Blocked)
   public RelationshipStatus RelationshipStatus {get;set;}

   public DateTime RelationshipCreationDate {get;set;}
}
```

Then in the model builder entity configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>().HasKey(r => new {r.UserId, r.FriendId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
    .HasOne(r => r.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.UserFriends)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
    .HasOne(r => r.Friend)
    .WithMany(f => f.FriendUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.FriendId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

Now it should work properly!